# Haskell: Data Modeling an Internal App that Interfaces with a 3rd-Party Library?

Tags: haskell, type-systems, data-types

I wrote a java [call graph](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Call_graph) generator with [tree sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) (the 3rd-party library in question)'s python binding. I am doing a thought experiment on how I might model the same application in Haskell. I am asking for help on designing the architecutre in Haskell. I have put forth a hypothesis, but if there's a better way in a different direction, please educate me on that :)

#### Prequel (Current Python Architecture):

Given a source file, `tree-sitter` returns the file's concrete syntax tree, with `Node` objects. A basic, `Node` object has the following abbreviated python type hint:

```
class Node(TypedDict):
    children: List[Node]
    text    : bytes 
    parent  : Optional[Node] // brackets in types are only used to feed type arguments and does not signify an array
    type    : str // Example values: "object_creation_expression", "identifier", "class_declaration"
```

I write a little parser function, intercepting basic tree-sitter Nodes and cast them into specific (and thus stronger) types, like:

```
class ClassDeclarationNode(Node): 
    children : Tuple[Optional[ModifierNode], ClassNameNode, ClassBodyNode],
    text     : bytes 
    parent   : ProgramNode | InterfaceDeclarationNode | ClassDeclarationNode // one of
```

and then I can write overload functions that uses Node for edge resolution like:

```
@overload
def resolveTypeOf(node: MethodInvocationNode) -> java_full_type: 
    return something
    
@overload
def resolveTypeOf(node: IdentifierNode) -> java_full_type: 
    return something
```

#### Haskell Hypothesis

In general, I want to develop a type system such that nodes passed around are "specific", like a `ClassDeclarationNode` instead of a basic `Node`. This is so that when I access the `children` field, I have the compile-time power of knowing that `children[0]` is a `Maybe ModifierNode`, `children[1]` is a `ClassNameNode` and `children[2]` is a `ClassBodyNode`.

First, I use `tree-sitter`'s haskell binding to read files and get a `tree-sitter` Haskell `Node`.

Then, I can model the data like:

```
data SpecificNode a b = SpecificNode { _children :: a, _parent :: b, _text :: Bytes, _type :: String }

type ClassDeclarationNode = SpecificNode (Maybe ModifierNode, ClassNameNode, ClassBodyNode) (__I'm stuck here__)
```

I don't know how to signify `OneOf[ProgramNode, InterfaceDeclarationNode, ClassDeclarationNode]`, which should go inside of "I'm stuck here".

And then I can write node type strictening functions like:

```
narrow :: Node -> SpecificNode a b
narrow n = case _type n of 
        "class_declaration" = SpecificNode { ... } -- prob have to do some recursion here to make sure the children become SpecificNodes first?
```

At last, my node functions look like

```
resolveTypeOf :: SpecificNode a b -> java_full_type
resolveTypeOf MethodInvocationNode = ... 
resolveTypeOf IdentifierNode       = ...
```

Additionally, there exists `tree-sitter-grammar.json` files. Here's the java [one](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-java/tree/master/src). Can I utilize these to automate writing out the specific `Node` types? And since there is a grammar file, can there be more "crazy" stuff I can do? Domain Specific Language?

##### Disclamer

This python code above wouldn't compile because the subtype says `children` is a `Tuple` but the parent-type says it's a `List`. I didn't implement the "casting into specific" functionality in my actual repo. I'm, however, pretending that's what my code does because it flows into the Haskell discussion.

Comment: Are you looking for an `Either a b` type? Or could you declare the type to be generic over its parent? Either case, I think this is more of a code level question that would be more suitable for the Haskell tag on [so].

Comment: @amon Thanks for the direction. I already declared the type to be generic. And I think, I was really looking for a `Either` type with arbitrarily many arguments (a `OneOf` type), which is an easy search on stackoverflow.